# Neo4j vs OpenLink Virtuoso

Tags: performance, neo4j, sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I've been using OpenLink Virtuoso as an RDF store for some time now and although it's great with large data, I'm not satisfied with the graph traversal performance using SPARQL. Recently I've heard a lot about Neo4j's traversal performance and thought it's worth a try. So, for the purpose of having a large RDF store with good traversal performance, is it better to switch to Neo4j?

I have no idea about Neo4j's performance with large data and well, the RDF/SPARQL part of Neo4j doesn't look that mature. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please see this transitive crawl example based on SPARQL. The backend has 29 Billion+ triples. Link: http://lod.openlinksw.com/b3s/search.vsp?q=6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtuoso ["Transitivity in SPARQL"](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlimplementatiotrans/)  would be the recommended method for graph traversal. We also have a [tutorial on Transitivity](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/presentations/SPARQL_Tutorials/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_2/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_2.html#%2828%29) providing some sample queries. Live example queries against our [LOD Cloud Cache (30+ billion triples)](http://lod.openlinksw.com/b3s/search.vsp?q=6) and [URIBurner (500+ million triples)](http://uriburner.com/demo_queries/search.vsp?q=6) instances are also available. Our blog post on [Virtuoso Transitivity and Graphs for SQL](http://www.openlinksw.com/weblog/oerling/?id=1433) would also make interesting reading ...

(Answered by Hugh Williams, OpenLink Software)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to jump on that. And one more question comes to my mind, how does querying over cURL reduce performance in comparison to ODBC or JDBC ?